# Exporting to and Formatting Excel through Access VBA - .Range Error

Tags: vba

I have been working on this for several days now and have read so much on the internet I am now blind and have no hair left. Very close to a solution but desperately need help.

I have a Access database that I made some queries to retrieve data from a table. I made a form with a button to click to export to Excel with multiple sheets.

I am trying to export with formatting and to see how that is done I converted the macro to Vb and I see how it is done but I cannot make the code create the workbook with multiple sheets and add some conditional formatting to column F.

The code that will export to Excel with access table formatting looks like this:

```
Private Sub Advance_Waiting_on_Visual_Report_Click()
On Error GoTo Advance_Waiting_on_Visual_Report_Click_Err

Const FileNameBase As String = "W:\Quality-Projects\RCabler\Databases\Weekly Reports\Waiting on Visual Weekly Report [CurrentDate].xlsx"
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = Replace(FileNameBase, "[CurrentDate]", Format$(Date, "m-dd-yyyy"))

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "AdvanceWaitVis", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", strFileName, True, "AdvanceWaitVis", , acExportQualityPrint

Advance_Waiting_on_Visual_Report_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

Advance_Waiting_on_Visual_Report_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Advance_Waiting_on_Visual_Report_Click_Exit

End Sub`
```

This will export the data to Excel with Access table formatting but I don't know how to add to it to make it do multiple sheets (by calling other queries) nor conditionally format column F to make the cells red if the date is 14 days old or older.

This code will export to Excel with multiple sheets but it does not transfer the Access table formatting and hangs on the line

```
.Range("F1:F" & lngRow).Select
```

and because of that hang it does not set the conditional formatting listed in the code after that line.

```
Code in Module named ExportFormatting


Public Function fnLastRow(sh As Object)
On Error Resume Next
With sh
fnLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=.Range("A1"), _
Lookat:=2, _
LookIn:=5, _
SearchOrder:=1, _
SearchDirection:=2, _
MatchCase:=False).row
End With
End Function


Code for button


Private Sub Command35_Click()

Const FileNameBase As String = "W:\Quality-Projects\RCabler\Databases\Weekly Reports\Waiting on Visual Weekly Report [CurrentDate].xlsx"
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = Replace(FileNameBase, "[CurrentDate]", Format$(Date, "m-dd-yyyy"))

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "AdvanceWaitVis", strFileName, True, "AdvanceWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ArcadiaWaitVis", strFileName, True, "ArcadiaWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "EcruWaitVis", strFileName, True, "EcruWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "LeesportWaitVis", strFileName, True, "LeesportWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "RipleyWaitVis", strFileName, True, "RipleyWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "WanekWaitVis", strFileName, True, "WanekWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "WanvogWaitVis", strFileName, True, "WanvogWaitVis"

Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlObj As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim lngRow As Long

Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlWB = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(strFileName, False, False)

For Each xlSheet In xlWB.Worksheets

With xlSheet

lngRow = fnLastRow(xlSheet)
Debug.Print lngRow

.Range("F1:F" & lngRow).Select
xlObj.Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=2, Formula1:= _
                "=TODAY()-F1<13"
  xlObj.Selection.FormatConditions(xlObj.Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With xlObj.Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
.PatternColorIndex = -4105
.Color = 255
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
xlObj.Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End With

Next
xlWB.Close True
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
xlObj.Quit
Set xlObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can someone please help me fix this code?

Comment: I understand there are 2 different button names in the above code... it is because I have 2 different buttons trying different things to get this to work. The code I need fixed can either be the first or second... I just need to be able to export with formatting to one workbook with multiple sheets and conditionally format column F to fill the cells red if the date value is 14 days old or older... if blank or less than 14 days old do nothing. Thank you in advance to anyone willing to help.

Comment: You  cannot select a range on a sheet which is not the ActiveSheet

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select a range on a sheet which is not the ActiveSheet, and in any case there's no need for a selection:

```
Dim rng As Object

'...

lngRow = fnLastRow(xlSheet)
Debug.Print lngRow

Set rng = xlSheet.Range("F1:F" & lngRow)
rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=2, Formula1:= _
                "=TODAY()-F1<13"
rng .FormatConditions(xlObj.Selection.FormatConditions.Count) _
           .SetFirstPriority

With rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = -4105
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

rng.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Comment: Just as before changing the code to as you suggest... it still throws an error in the same place but it is your line that highlights in the debugger `Set rng = xlSheet.Range("F1:F" & lngRow)` . It did create the file as before but no formatting of the cells since it hung on that line.

Comment: What's the value of lngRow when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like this now

```
Private Sub Command35_Click()

Const FileNameBase As String = "W:\Quality-Projects\RCabler\Databases\Weekly Reports\Waiting on Visual Weekly Report [CurrentDate].xlsx"
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = Replace(FileNameBase, "[CurrentDate]", Format$(Date, "m-dd-yyyy"))

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "AdvanceWaitVis", strFileName, True, "AdvanceWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "ArcadiaWaitVis", strFileName, True, "ArcadiaWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "EcruWaitVis", strFileName, True, "EcruWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "LeesportWaitVis", strFileName, True, "LeesportWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "RipleyWaitVis", strFileName, True, "RipleyWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "WanekWaitVis", strFileName, True, "WanekWaitVis"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "WanvogWaitVis", strFileName, True, "WanvogWaitVis"

Dim rng As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlObj As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim lngRow As Long

Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlWB = xlObj.Workbooks.Open(strFileName, False, False)

For Each xlSheet In xlWB.Worksheets

    With xlSheet


        lngRow = fnLastRow(xlSheet)
        Debug.Print lngRow

        Set rng = xlSheet.Range("F1:F" & lngRow)
rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=2, Formula1:= _
            "=TODAY()-F1<13"
rng .FormatConditions(xlObj.Selection.FormatConditions.Count) _
       .SetFirstPriority

With rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior
.PatternColorIndex = -4105
.Color = 255
.TintAndShade = 0
End With

rng.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End With

Next
xlWB.Close True
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
xlObj.Quit
Set xlObj = Nothing

End Sub
```